# Docker execution slower on EC2 host

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2, docker

We have recently created a docker image to run the Terraspace tool for executing our CI/CD in GitLab pipelines. The container uses `ruby:3.0.2-alpine` for it's upstream, for reference.

The problem we're facing is that it is extremely slow when executed on EC2 (m5.large), here are some timings that include running the tool inside the docker image and natively on the host. The docker timings are performed inside the image after it has already been downloaded.

| EC2 Docker | EC2 | Local Docker | Local |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| real 5m33.403s | real 0m44.799s | real 1m40.842s | real 0m39.626s |
| user 0m11.150s | user 0m26.531s | user 0m24.736s | user 0m10.913s |
| sys 0m1.437s | sys 0m3.276s | sys 0m13.846s | sys 0m4.580 |

The slower execution inside docker is also true for the standard terraspace image `boltops/terraspace`.

It doesn't appear to be a resource usage issue as there are plenty of resources left on the host during execution

```
CONTAINER ID   NAME            CPU %     MEM USAGE / LIMIT    MEM %     NET I/O          BLOCK I/O     PIDS
9b05765250b8   quirky_spence   0.54%     1.21GiB / 7.583GiB   15.95%    300MB / 3.43MB   0B / 1.08MB   3
```

Here is the docker machine info:

```
lient:
 Context:    default
 Debug Mode: false

Server:
 Containers: 4
  Running: 0
  Paused: 0
  Stopped: 4
 Images: 3
 Server Version: 20.10.4
 Storage Driver: overlay2
  Backing Filesystem: xfs
  Supports d_type: true
  Native Overlay Diff: true
 Logging Driver: json-file
 Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
 Cgroup Version: 1
 Plugins:
  Volume: local
  Network: bridge host ipvlan macvlan null overlay
  Log: awslogs fluentd gcplogs gelf journald json-file local logentries splunk syslog
 Swarm: inactive
 Runtimes: io.containerd.runc.v2 io.containerd.runtime.v1.linux runc
 Default Runtime: runc
 Init Binary: docker-init
 containerd version: d71fcd7d8303cbf684402823e425e9dd2e99285d
 runc version: %runc_commit
 init version: de40ad0
 Security Options:
  seccomp
   Profile: default
 Kernel Version: 4.14.238-182.422.amzn2.x86_64
 Operating System: Amazon Linux 2
 OSType: linux
 Architecture: x86_64
 CPUs: 2
 Total Memory: 7.583GiB
 Name: ip-10-0-4-227
 ID: FUYW:PCXQ:5ZFW:4SMP:YIG4:RNBH:HCMH:6R53:NHS2:HTJO:VAKM:5QFB
 Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
 Debug Mode: false
 Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
 Labels:
 Experimental: false
 Insecure Registries:
  127.0.0.0/8
 Registry Mirrors:
  https://docker-proxy/
 Live Restore Enabled: false
```

Any help would be appreciated on this.

Comment: Check your DNS.

Comment: Just checked, DNS is fine. No issues resolving from within the container.

Comment: Interesting. Well, the numbers say that it's spending a lot of time in the container _doing nothing_, i.e. waiting for something, where this time is not really being consumed when run outside the container. Usually this is a DNS problem though it could just be a general connectivity issue, or something else entirely that the app is spending its time waiting for.

Comment: I/O would be my next guess.